# Create an external module in Angular 4

Tags: angular, npm, module, npm-link

I want create an external module and then import it into my project.

I create a simple module ( widget.module.ts ) that have a component ( widget.component.ts ), so i generate a package.json file using npm

```
npm init --scope=@mylibs
# i give the name widget
# the entrypoint is widget.module.js

npm install
# it create node_module folder

npm link
# it create the link
```

then i create a simple app

```
ng new MySimpleApp
```

in the MySimpleApp path i link my module

```
npm link @mylibs/widget
```

but when i launch my app

```
ng serve
```

i have this error:

**'WidgetModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.**

Comment: Have you placed the **@NgModule** decorator in your WidgetModule?

Comment: It works exactly the same if the module was in your `src` folder. The only difference is the import paths are not relative. That means typescript should be resolving imports to your node_modules when they are explicit.

Comment: yes, my module have the @NgModule decorator, and in my app there is the @mylibs/widget folder under the node_module folder. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I'm thinking this is because of an issue I read about. Angular doesn't support it well when there's a separate dependency on Angular. Basically, in your package you have a different `instance` of `NgModule` then in your main application, which causes this confusion.

I'm looking for an answer to this problem myself, so no real further help there.